# Whitelist file extensions in directory?

Tags: filesystems

Is it possible to whitelist specific file extensions for folders?

For example: I would like to move music albums to a folder, but I don't want the cover art to be transferred by disallowing *.png, *.jpg, etc.,...

Comment: Look into `rsync`, it has multiple filter options.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do the filtering on copying, say, in the copy script. Or you can apply the filter after the copy operation, removing what's not *allowed* or needed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is certainly **broader** than the issue so the answer may vary.

Originally, Unix-like systems do not know the concept of file extension although some software may identify extensions to adapt their operations.

Moreover, a *pathname expansion* must match  existing files or directories located on a specified level in the file system (hierarchical filesystem).

`mv` can move an entire directory hierarchy, therefore, `mv` also moves files located in matching directories, indistinctly.

A simple solution is to remove the read permission on the wanted files to prevent them to be copied.

```
prompt% cp -vr album /tmp
'album/' -> '/tmp/album'
'album/song.mp3' -> '/tmp/album/song.mp3'
'album/covert.png' -> '/tmp/album/covert.png'
 cp: cannot open 'album/covert.png' for reading: Permission denied
prompt% ls -l album/covert.png
--w-r--r-- user user 8 Sep 07:27 album/covert.png
```

Files are transferred in the target directory except files that are protected for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The naive way to solve this is to copy everything and then to delete the file you don't want.

Using `rsync` to copy the whole `source` directory structure to `target`, then `find` to delete the files you don't want from `target`:

```
rsync -a source/ target

find target -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -delete
```

A more streamlined way to do this is to use the filtering capabilities of `rsync` to not transfer the files you don't want:

```
rsync -a --exclude='*.png' --exclude='*.jpg' source/ target
```

In both of these cases, you might possibly want to add `--delete` and/or `--delete-excluded` to the `rsync` invocation if you want to delete files not present in the source directory (if `target` already contains stuff and you want the two directories to be *identical* apart from those image files).